# Splitting the cells in a pandas DataFrame by whitespace

Tags: python, pandas, split, transformation

I have a Pandas DataFrame (we'll call it 'cardiac') with 10 columns and 200 rows. Each of the column cells contain multiple values separated by whitespace. While there are 10 columns in each row and varying values in each row, there are actually 76 separate values divided among these 10 rows by whitespace that need to go in 76 distinct columns. So one row of 'cardiac' dataframe looks like this (with 76 values total):

```
column01: 1254 0 40 1 1 0 0
column02: -9 2 140 0 289 -9 -9 -9
column03: 0 -9 -9 0 12 16 84 0
column04: 0 0 0 0 150 18 -9 7
column05: 172 86 200 110 140 86 0 0
column06: 0 -9 26 20 -9 -9 -9 -9
column07: -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 12
column08: 20 84 0 -9 -9 -9 -9 -9
column09: -9 -9 -9 -9 -9 1 1 1
column10: 1 1 -9. -9. name
```

What I want to do is preserve my 200 rows but split the data in each column by the whitespaces as separators, to end up with a dataframe of 200 rows and 76 columns.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with complete input and desired output.

Comment: are the columns currently each being read in as a string?

Comment: @ALollz Yes, they are being read in as strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here's an example. The loop basically string splits every element in the columns, based on whitespace. `Tempdf` is then a temporary dataframe with many rows (in your case 200), and only a single column, whose elements are a single list (in your case of all 76 values). The final line then explodes that list so that every element goes in a single column.

If each row truly has 76 values, they will be filled in order. Otherwise, as in this example, `None` gets placed in columns since the rows did not actually have the same number of whitespace separated elements.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'row_name': ['row01', 'row02'],
                  'text_1': ['1254 0 1 1 0', '11 21 -9. -'],
                  'text_2': ['1 1 -9. name', '1 1 -9. -9. e name'],
                  'text_3': ['176 0 0 0 -9 -9', '176 0 -99 -99 name 199  0']})
#   row_name       text_1          text_2                 text_3
#0  row01         1254 0 1         1 1 -9.         176 0 0 0 -9 -9
#1  row02         11 21 -9. -  1 1 -9. e name  176 0 -99 name 199  0

vs = pd.Series()
for col in df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['row_name'])]:
    vs = vs.append(df[col].str.split('\s+'))

tempdf = vs.groupby(vs.index).sum().to_frame()
finaldf = pd.DataFrame(tempdf[0].values.tolist())

#     0   1    2  3  4  5    6  7     8    9  10   11    12   13    14
#0  1254   0    1     1  1  -9.      176    0  0    0    -9   -9  None
#1    11  21  -9.  -  1  1  -9.  e  name  176  0  -99  name  199     0
```